# Understanding the dots in variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Suppose I have the following piece of code. Which I understand to a large extent.

```
template <class ...Args>               //---> Statement A
void foo_imp(const Args&... args)      //---> Statement B
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {args...};  //---> Statement C
}
```

Now I am a bit confused as to where the `...` should appear before or after the name of the variable. Here is why I am confused.

The statement A, given below

```
template <class ...Args>
```

suggests that `...` is the variable type and Args is the variable name (which is fine)

The statement B, given below

```
void foo_imp(const Args&... args)
```

This seems to me like the type is Args which was the template type however the addition of `...` after `Args` confuses me?

and then assigning the value to vector is further confusing

```
 std::vector<int> vec = { args... };
```

why are there `...` after args ?

Any ideas on how I could remember the above code so that it would make sense to me ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<class ...Args>` declares `Args` to be a variadic parameter pack where the (meta-)type of each parameter is `class`. For the sake of this explanation, let's suppose this can be thought of as similar to:

```
<class Args1, class Args2, class Args3, etc.>
```

Variadic type parameter packs can appear wherever lists of types may appear, but must be expanded with `...`. So for example `void foo_imp(Args)` is not legal, but

```
void foo_imp(Args...)
```

would be equivalent to

```
void foo_imp(Args1, Args2, Args3, etc.)
```

The `...` expands the thing to its left, using the values of the parameter pack. So in your actual example,

```
void foo_imp(const Args&...)
```

would be equivalent to

```
void foo_imp(const Args1&, const Args2&, const Args3&, etc.)
```

Now it is time to abandon the idea of the template parameter pack as a fixed sized list of types; in actuality, its length is determined by the number of arguments supplied at call time.

*"BUT WE DON'T SUPPLY ANY TEMPLATE ARGUMENTS AT CALL TIME!?!"* I hear you say. This is because `foo_imp` is a function whose template arguments are deduced on the basis of its normal arguments. This means that the length of the `(const Args1&, const Args2&, const Args3&)` list is determined by the function call, and each `ArgsN` type is determined by the normal rules for function template type deduction.

---

Now on to `args`. Similarly to `Args`, `args` is a variadic parameter pack, and so must be expanded whenever it is used.

```
std::vector<int> vec = {args...};
```

is equivalent to (using our explanatory naming system from earlier)

```
std::vector<int> vec = {args1, args2, args3, etc.};
```

Variadic parameter packs do not automatically expand themselves, because they can be expanded as part of larger expressions, and so automatic expansion could be ambiguous or incorrect. For example:

```
std::forward<Args>(args)...
//expands as:
std::forward<Args1>(args1), std::forward<Args2>(args2), std::forward<Args3>(args3), etc.
```

is able to work because it individually forwards each argument. If it were expanded as

```
std::forward<Args...>(args...)
//expands as:
std::forward<Args1, Args2, Args3, etc.>(args1, args2, args3, etc)
```

it wouldn't even compile, because `std::forward` only takes a single parameter.

---

In conclusion. If `...` appears to the right of an expression containing any variadic parameter packs, it expands that expression as a list, with each element of the list having the nth value from every contained parameter pack in place of that parameter pack.

```
//Foo and bar are variadic parameter packs
Foo...                     => Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc
std::vector<Foo>...        => std::vector<Foo1>, std::vector<Foo2>, std::vector<Foo3>, etc.
std::tuple<Foo...>(bar...) => std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc>(bar1, bar2, bar3, etc)
&bar...                    => &bar1, &bar2, &bar3, etc
```

If such an expanded expression appears in a parameter list, it can be captured by a variadic parameter pack variable. In this case, if the expression does not contain any variadic parameter packs, the parameter list is freed to take an arbitrary number of parameters.

```
template<typename ...Baz> => Baz is a variable length variadic parameter pack of `typename`s
void bar(Baz ...baz)      => baz is a parameter pack of `Baz`s
void bar(Baz &&...baz)    => baz is a parameter pack of `Baz&&`s
```

Comment: What a fantastic answer! I've been struggling with the exact same problem. Thank you for taking the time to right such an excellent and detailed answer.