# Variadic Templates - Parameter pack expansion understanding

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am having a hard time understanding parameter pack expansion.
The thing that confuses me are when dots appear on the right side and when dots appear on the left side. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485643/understanding-the-dots-in-variadic-template-function) post which helped a little.
Suppose I have the following two examples

```
Example 1:
template <class ...A>   --> line 1
int func(A... arg)      --> line 2
{
   return sizeof...(arg);
}

int main(void)
{
   return func(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

The post I mentioned above I believe mentions that the difference b/w `...A` and `A...` is that the first one does Left side expansion and the second one does right side expansion. I am not sure what that means. Could anyone please clarify this with how something would look like when expanded. The only thing I understand so far regarding dots on the right hand side are the examples such as this

```
//Foo and bar are variadic parameter packs
Foo...                     => Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc
std::vector<Foo>...        => std::vector<Foo1>, std::vector<Foo2>, std::vector<Foo3>, etc.
std::tuple<Foo...>(bar...) => std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc>(bar1, bar2, bar3, etc)
&bar...                    => &bar1, &bar2, &bar3, etc
```

could any one please clarify what the dots expand to in line 1 and line 2 and what is the difference between left side expansion and right side expansion ?

Comment: The spaces around the dots don't matter. So `class ...A` is equivalent to `class... A`, and `A... arg` is equivalent to `A ...arg`. Only `sizeof...` cannot have spaces.

Comment: @dyp Are you sure about `sizeof...`?

Comment: @T.C. Not entirely. There are some hints in the standard, like *"The `sizeof...` operator"*..

Comment: @dyp Well, I can find no `sizeof...` token, so I don't see why there can't be spaces.

Comment: @T.C. Ok, I retract that statement about `sizeof`. There are spaces in the BNFs, and both g++ and clang++ accept `sizeof ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for the "..." token in the context of variadic template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652412/what-are-the-rules-for-the-token-in-the-context-of-variadic-template)

Answer (score 5):

There is no "left-side expansion", there is only "right-side expansion." When you typed:

```
template <class ...A>
int func(A... arg)
```

The `...` does not apply to the `A`. It helps to think of it as:

```
 template <class... A>
```

As in, `A` names a parameter-pack consisting of `class`es. There is no expansion going on in that line - it's just declaring what the parameters are for the function template `func`.

Furthermore, as [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659769/variadic-templates-parameter-pack-expansion-understanding/31659993?noredirect=1#comment51265074_31659993) points out, the `...` in the argument list grammatically binds to the argument name not its type. This helps make sense of particularly complicated declarations such as:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(T (*...fs)());
```

where `fs` would be a (possibly-empty) pack of pointers to nullary functions.

As for parameter pack expansion, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767333/2069064) for a list of examples of what parameter expansion does based on the `...` placement. The short version is: all the packs in the expression immediately preceding the `...` are expanded concurrently. All of the examples you listed in your question are correct. I would additionally add:

```
std::tuple<Foo...>(bar...) => std::tuple<Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc>(bar1, bar2, bar3, etc)
std::tuple<Foo>(bar)...    => std::tuple<Foo1>(bar1), std::tuple<Foo2>(bar2), ...
```

Comment: I would say that `class ...A` is about *contraction*, not expansion. Turning a group of types into one pack. Whereas `A...` is about expansion, expanding one pack into a group of types. e.g. if you explicitly call `func<int, char, double>(1,'1',1.0)` then you a *building* a pack, not *expanding* it.

Comment: It's useful to know that in `A ...args`, the `...` binds to `args` as a matter of grammar, though. Some crazier declarators don't make much sense unless you know that.

Comment: @T.C. Updated, with crazy declarator.